# Get DataType / DataTemplateKey

Tags: c#, win-universal-app, uwp, windows-10-universal

I'm trying to retrieve the DataTemplateKey of a DataTemplate which is defined in a Resource.

```
    <DataTemplate x:Key="Cell" x:DataType="model:Cell">
        <CheckBox IsChecked="{Binding Empty}" ></CheckBox>
    </DataTemplate>
```

I'm able to access the DataTemplate in the codebehind, but the DataTemplate doesn't contain any information about the DataTemplateKey.

```
var bla = DataTemplate.GetType().GetTypeInfo();
```

I tried to get/read the DataType by Reflection, but I can't find it.

Is the x:DataType a attached propertie? I can't find the proper class.

How can I get the DataType of the DataTemplate

Answer (score 1):

```
 var key = new System.Windows.DataTemplateKey(typeof(YourViewModel));
 var dataTemplate = (DataTemplate)this.FindResource(key);

 var tc = dataTemplate.LoadContent().GetType();
```

Try use this

Comment: dataTemplate.LoadContent().GetType() returns for my DataTemplate the Type of CheckBox

Comment: In uwp there also does not exist FindResource(key) in the Resource class. You can use only FindName().